# EMR conf spark-default settings

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, configuration, amazon-emr

I am using configuration file according to guides [Configure Spark](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-configure.html) to setup EMR configuration on AWS, for example, changing the `spark.executor.extraClassPath` is via the following settings:

```
{
     "Classification": "spark-defaults",
     "Properties": {
         "spark.executor.extraClassPath": "/home/hadoop/mongo-hadoop-spark.jar",
     }
}
```

It works prefect and do change `spark.executor.extraClassPath` on emr spark conf, but emr has some preset default paths in `spark.executor.extraClassPath`, so instead of overwriting the `spark.executor.extraClassPath`.I would like to know if there is a way to append the path and keep the default paths such as

```
{
     "Classification": "spark-defaults",
     "Properties": {
         "spark.executor.extraClassPath": "{$extraClassPath}:/home/hadoop/mongo-hadoop-spark.jar",
     }
}
```

Comment: I can manually supply the defaults path by copy & paste, but I want to remain the consistent default path from AWS.

Comment: The issue here is that it's not a `spark.executor.extraClassPath` isn't a environement variable, so you'll not be able to use export to append one path to the other....

Comment: yeah, I know. Maybe I need to do it in a dirty way...By adding a step to the emr bootstrap after spark conf is present, use `sed` to grep the line and append the path...@eliasah

Answer (score 1):

You can specify it in your emr template as follows

```
Classification: spark-defaults
          ConfigurationProperties:
            spark.jars: Your jar location
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifying full path for all additional jars  while job sumit will work for you.

-- jars

This option Will submit these jars to all the executors and will not change default extra classpath

One more option I know but I only tried it with Yarn conf  not sure about EMR though

./bin/spark-submit --class "SparkTest" --master local[*] --jars /fullpath/first.jar,/fullpath/second.jar /fullpath/your-program.jar

Comment: Adding `--jars` helps the case when submitting the spark job, whereas we also use notebook which it takes spark conf for the notebook setup.

Comment: With notebook you mean local setup for development?

Comment: No, emr integrated notebook, which is a selectable option for emr setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can put "spark.jars" in `spark-defaults.conf` so even if you are using notebook this configuration will be used. Hope it will solve your problem

Comment: I tried {
     "Classification": "spark-defaults",
     "Properties": {
         "spark.jars": "/home/hadoop/mongo-hadoop-spark.jar", 
     }
} doesn't work

Comment: and I tried { "Classification": "spark-defaults", "Properties": { "spark.jars": ["/home/hadoop/mongo-hadoop-spark.jar"], }  failed with when I am trying to create a cluster.